# Is it possible to access DB2 from Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: db2, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a question about SQL developer – I have a need to connect to DB2 for data extract or just to browse DB2 tables. Is this possible from to do this from SQL Developer? If so, how can this be setup? If not what are my options or alternatives to access DB2 from SQL Developer?

Any and all assistance will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Okonita

Comment: See answer, but watch out!

Comment: @javapapo What *answer*? Or perhaps the answer to which that 07-Jan comment refers, was since deleted, as was an answer that was posted earlier today?

Comment: @CRPence have u red the post?

Comment: @javapapo This topic shows **no answers** when ***I*** view. Deleted posts are not visible to me [per not yet having reached a 10K reputation], so if there are deleted answers on this topic, I would not know. Maybe you see your deleted answer? Or maybe I still do not understand what *answer* to which you referred in the first comment to the OP.?